# Spring Cloud Gateway Entering Infinite Loop When Routing to Angular App

Tags: angular, spring, api-gateway, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm working with Spring Cloud Gateway to route requests to an Angular app, but I'm encountering an issue where the Spring Cloud Gateway enters into an infinite loop. The logs show that the same ui route is being matched repeatedly. This causes a 431 Error Reponse that the header is too bug. For debugging purposes I have already set it 5MB

Here's a snippet of my Spring Cloud Gateway configuration in application.yml:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: ui
          uri: http://localhost:4200
          predicates:
            - Path=/ui/**
```

And here the relevant logs

```
2023-10-07T10:14:37.555+02:00 DEBUG 18114 --- [ioEventLoop-5-1] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Route matched: ui
2023-10-07T10:14:37.555+02:00 DEBUG 18114 --- [ioEventLoop-5-1] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Mapping [Exchange: GET http://localhost:9000/ui/] to Route{id='ui', uri=http://localhost:4200, order=0, predicate=Paths: [/ui/**], match trailing slash: true, gatewayFilters=[[[DedupeResponseHeader Access-Control-Allow-Credentials Access-Control-Allow-Origin = RETAIN_FIRST], order = 1], [[SaveSession], order = 2]], metadata={}}
...
(repeated ~50 times)
```

Things I've already tried:

Made sure that Angular app and Spring Cloud Gateway are running on different ports.
Checked custom filters and Websocket configuration.
Increased the header size limit to 5MB using server.max-http-header-size.
Any idea what might be causing these issues and how to resolve them?